# Convert Mysql.connector dtypes objects to numeric/ string

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an SQL query with mysql.connector in python 3. I m converting the result of fetchall to a pandas Dataframe.

```
mycursor.execute(sql_query)
m_table = pd.DataFrame(mycursor.fetchall()) 
m_table.columns = [i[0] for i in mycursor.description]
```

Getting dtypes gives me :

```
Out[185]: 
sales_forecast_id          int64
year                       int64
products_id                int64
test_string               object
reconduit                  int64
target_week_1              int64
target_week_2              int64
year_n_1                   int64
two_week_before           object
first_week_before         object
second_week_before        object
two_week_before_n_1       object
first_week_before_n_1     object
second_week_before_n_1    object
CIBLE_n_1                  int64
dtype: object
```

Test_string is a fake column I added for testing and it contains `"test"` in all rows.

Now this `test_string` column and the other from `two_week_before` to `second_week_before_n_1` appears as dtype object. So `test_string` is a string in database and the other are decimal. But with the dtype object I can't perform multiplication with another float typed column.

Now, I actually have hundreds of this columns, and I would like to convert all the dtype object to float when its a decimal/int and to string when it's a string.

How can I do it automatically. How to know if the object is a string or a decimal?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `try` to convert everything into float, and except to conver it into a string (object). Does that sound good for you?

Comment: That what I was thinking as a "workaround" but thought there would be something cleaner. It should do the trick. thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easy way to apply this conversion to all columns in case you **are sure** you need them **all** to be transformed into floats except the ones that can't (because they contain strings):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = {'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':['a','b','aa','abc'],'c':[100,13,14,'xD']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['a'] = df['a'].astype('object')
print(df.dtypes)
```

Output (where column `a` is of type `object` when it should be `int` or `float`):

```
a    object
b    object
c    object
dtype: object
```

Applying the following:

```
for i in list(data):
    try:
        df[i] = df[i].astype('float')
    except ValueError:
        df[i] = df[i].astype('object')
print(df.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
a    float64
b     object
c     object
dtype: object
```